# Why can't I update to the latest version of nativescript-theme (nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

Using the latest nativescript core w/ Android 6.5

In the project file, I see I'm using nativescript-theme 2.2.1

I see the latest version is 2.3.4.

I do `npm outdated` on the command line and nativescript-theme is not listed.

Anyone know why I cannot update to the latest version?

I also did `npm outdated @nativescript/theme`.

Comment: Did you try `npm i @nativescript/theme`? You can remove the older version once you install the new scoped package.

Comment: ok I did that and got the latest...but can you tell me why `npm outdated` wasn't showing it. Also how do I remove the old version. Thanks.